# Not able to look in the contents of folder by pressing Enter in Intelij

Tags: intellij-idea

I am not able to see contents of folder by pressing Enter Button in project in Intellij

Step to reproduce:

1. Go to any root project
2. Press Enter

I am getting navigated to Project Structures window.

Note: I have updated my Intellij version to the latest that's why facing this.

Answer (score 0):

It's a known issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-249246. Will be fixed in 2020.2.3.